# Can I get HotChocolate to Execute Cosmos DB Query after Middleware Asynchronously?

Tags: graphql, azure-cosmosdb, hotchocolate

I'm trying to implement a function that exposed a query on GraphQL using HotChocolate and CosmosDb. I'd like to use the sorting and filtering options HotChocolate provides however when it's running, I'm running into the following exceptions:

```
To execute LINQ query please set allowSynchronousQueryExecution true or use GetItemQueryIterator to execute asynchronously
```

I am therefore assuming that HotChocolate runs through all its middleware linq statements fine and then executes the query on the DB but in a synchronous manner which is throwing exceptions. I know there is an option to return all the models and do the sorting and filtering in memory but the data set can be very large and that's not ideal. Is there a way to get HotChocolate to run the middleware without execution and then execute the SQL query Asynchronously?

The code for my query is below.

```
[UseSorting]
[UseFiltering]
public IQueryable<U> GetAll(IResolverContext context)
{
    var allDbModels = _repository.GetAll();

    var models = allDbModels.Select(dbModel => _mapper.Map<U>(dbModel));

    return models;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this offering on Azure Cosmos DB? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/announcing-data-api-builder-for-azure-cosmos-db/